# Matplotlib "expected end of text" in column name

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

I have a pandas dataframe with a column whose name ends in two dollar signs ("$$").  I can pass this column name into various pandas methods (e.g. loc, apply) without issue.  However, when I try to include the column in a seaborn relplot, I get this error:

```
File "[snip]\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\mathtext.py", line 3293, in parse

box = self._parser.parse(s, font_output, fontsize, dpi)

ValueError:
Prior Year $$
           ^
Expected end of text (at char 11), (line:1, col:12)
```

Changing the column name to end in only one dollar sign (i.e. "Prior Year $") fixes the bug.  So my question is, why does the parser get confused by the second dollar sign?

Comment: Two dollar signs are interpreted as [MathText](https://matplotlib.org/tutorials/text/mathtext.html) (similar to latex math-mode) in matplotlib.